# How do i call default function from different component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want call a component containing a function with parameters from different components like so:- 
I have component (A) containing the following:

```
export default doSomething = (key,value) =>{
firebase.database().ref('ref/').update({
    key:value
});}
```

And I wanted to use (A) in a couple of components (B) and (C) like :

```
import A from 'Path';
render(){ 
   var name={};
   return (<Button onPress={()=><A key={name} value="Any Name"/>}/>)
}
```

Firstly, what is the best way to call (A)? 
Secondly, calling key like I called name never gave an error and never worked. I did console.log() and the output was object, so how do I call key the right way?

Comment: `doSomething` is not a component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`doSomething` (`A`) is not a component, just a function. Also, there may be problems with `export default doSomething = ...` syntax because it requires `doSomething` variable to be previously defined, which isn't shown.

In case `key` is not property name but a variable that contains property name, computed property should be used.

It should be:

```
export default (key, value) => {
    firebase.database().ref('ref/').update({
        [key]: value
    });
}
```

And be used as (another answer already mentions this):

```
<Button onPress={() => A(name, "Any Name")}/>
```

Comment: that for the first issue and how do i call the key ?

Comment: I updated the answer but I'm not sure if this is what you're asking about. `var name={}` won't work in this case. It should contain the name of the property.

Comment: var name={} wont work like this but it worked like var name='name' as string, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your export by default in A is a method, so :

```
onPress={() => A(name, "AnyName")}
```

Comment: You can't return a component in an onPress property